# Tenant Service not working

Tags: data-exchange-framework, identity-server

I'm using `Data Exchange Framework` and Tenant Service in Sitecore 9.1 with `identity server` on, and while testing the Tenant Service site with `[host]/api/tenant` request I constantly getting "**login failed**" error in the logs of Tenant Service web site.

But I'm sure I have a correct connection string for my Tenant Service web site. May this error have some relations to the `Identity Server`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This generally happens when your Sitecore instances doesn't have `SSL` binding enabled.

This is happening because the `Tenant Service` is using the `Sitecore Client Services RESTful API` to authenticate against the Sitecore Instance and the authentication method only responds over `HTTPS`. You can find more on the topic here - [The RESTful API for the ItemService](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html)

Keep in mind that for your local instance, you should be free to use a non-valid self-signed certificate for your IIS binding. (i.e. random xConnect one)